# Generar 10 cartas de la baraja española sin repeticiones

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio en el que debo generar 10 cartas de la baraja española de forma aleatoria sin que se repita la misma carta. **No puedo generar directamente las 48 cartas y luego sacar 10** por requisitos del problema.

Entonces, tengo que conseguir de forma DIRECTA generar las 10 cartas sin que se repita. La única manera en la que se me ocurre resolver esto es comparar la nueva carta generada con las anteriores que ya se han metido (Esto es el segundo `for`) y si hay alguna igual quitarle a la `i--` un valor y que pruebe otra vez, y si no está repetida pues que meta en el `arrayList` la nueva carta generada.

Como veis, el código parece estar correctamente, pero cuando lo ejecutas varias veces siempre hay alguna carta que se repite, es decir, el mismo numero y palo y esto no tiene que ser así.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ejercicio8Baraja {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Objetos
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Baraja> cartas = new ArrayList<Baraja>(10);
        //variables
        int palo = 0, numero = 0, n = 0;
        String palorandom = "";

        numero = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 1 + 1) + 1); // Valor entre M y N, ambos incluidos.
        //System.out.print(numero);
        palo = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1) + 1); // Valor entre M y N, ambos incluidos.
        if (palo == 1) {
            palorandom = "Oros";
        } else if (palo == 2) {
            palorandom = "Bastos";
        } else if (palo == 3) {
            palorandom = "Espadas";
        } else {
            palorandom = "Copas";
        }
        cartas.add(new Baraja(numero, palorandom));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Principio primer for");
            numero = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 1 + 1) + 1);
            palo = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1) + 1);
            if (palo == 1) {
                palorandom = "Oros";
            } else if (palo == 2) {
                palorandom = "Bastos";
            } else if (palo == 3) {
                palorandom = "Espadas";
            } else {
                palorandom = "Copas";
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < cartas.size(); j++) {
                n += 2;
                //System.out.println("Principio segundo for"+n);
                if (numero == cartas.get(j).getNumero() && palorandom.equals(cartas.get(j).getPalo())) {
                    i--;
                    break;
                } else {
                    cartas.add(new Baraja(numero, palorandom));
                    break;
                }
                //System.out.println("Final segundo for");
            }


        } //fin primer for

        //mostrar la baraja española
        for (Baraja b: cartas) {
            System.out.print(b.toString());
        }

    } //main
} //clase
```

Comment: Lo habitual es obtener la baraja ordenada, desordenar, y sacar 10.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus molestias pero no has ayudado en nada, mi duda es esta porque es un ejercicio  y necesito que se haga de esta manera, a parte, si sigues las leyes del buen programador no vas a meter las 48 cartas a mano, las generaria del mismo modo que estoy haciendo para las 10 cartas solo que para 48 y nos encontramos en el mismo problema de antes.

Comment: Para insertar una nueva carta tienes que comprobar que no coincida con **ninguna** de las que ya tienes; pero tu código inserta la carta tan pronto como encuentras que hay alguna de las que ya tienes que no es igual a la nueva carta. Repasa el álgebra booleana y en particular las leyes de De Morgan. Aparte de eso, cambiar el valor del índice (`i`) de un `for` dentro del bucle es muy feo.

Comment: la idea de PaperBirdMaster tampoco es mala, pues si tu programa va a trabajar con una baraja, es logico tenerla en un array y operar con ella. (en otras funciones tendras que utilizar ciertas cartas, u operar con ellas de otra manera). Otra forma es que tengas un array vacio, generes una carta, compruebes que no existe, y si es el caso, la añades al array. Cuando el array tenga 10 cartas, has resuelto tu problema. La condicion de salida sera que la cuenta de ese array sea 10 elementos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus molestias pero tú tampoco ayudas en nada. Para tener una respuesta que se ajuste a tus necesidades, lo principal es dejar claras cuáles son estas, y el por qué de las mismas. Mi propuesta es la más correcta a nivel de distribución homogénea de elementos, si tu prioridad es otra, debes decirlo. Por otro lado, si tu prioridad es que te hagan el ejercicio, te recomiendo en primer lugar un cambio de actitud, y en segundo lugar una edición de la pregunta para ajustarse a lo que he comentado.

Comment: _PaperBirdMaster_ Lo siento si no me he explicado correctamente, mi intención no es que me hagan el ejercicio, a mí me gusta comprender el porqué de las cosas y resolverlas por mí mismo, pues vosotros no me haréis los examenes, a todo esto, lo que ha dicho _SJuan76_ no le quito razón ninguna, pero sigo sin comprender a que se refiere con que inserto la carta conforme hay un hueco, es cierto realizo esa acción pero creo que con el _cartas.size()_ estoy comprobando el array entero.

Comment: @VladyRuso Lo que dijo PaperBirdMaster es lo que tienes que hacer: genera las 48 cartas en orden, sin aletoriedad, y luego barájalas. No uses Random para generarlas, sino para barajarlas (intercambiar posiciones)

Comment: Puedes hacer lo que propone @PaperBirdMaster, esto es: Llenas un ArrayList con las barajas en orden (del 1 al 48), luego desordenas dicho ArrayList (*scramble*) y por último escoges 10 elementos diferentes. Otra forma es saltarte el paso de *scramble*, y escoger 10 elementos de tu ArrayList aleatoriamente. Cada vez que escoges un elemento, debes eliminarlo de las opciones para que no se repita.

Comment: @PabloLozano otra posibilidad es, teniendo un listado de N cartas, sacar una de ellas al azar (número aleatorio entre 0 y N-1) y guardarla en otro listado, repetir hasta llegar a 10 (teniendo en cuenta que N es cada vez más pequeño).

Comment: @VladyRuso de la forma de la que estas haciendo el programa y me imagino que es como quieres hacerlo, la única solución que se me ocurre para decirte es que el número junto con el palo lo guardes en otro arraylist , esto sería con el  priemero que generes,  con el segundo tendrías que comprobar si concide con el que creaste antes que se encuentra en el arraylist que te e dicho que creeases y si no está repetido lo guardas tanto en este como en donde guardas las 10 cartas; y así sucesivamente. Es un poco lo que decía SJuan76 de comprobar las cartas que escojes. Espero que te sirva esto. :D

Comment: Muchas gracias, probaré resolver el ejercicio de esta manera después del examen que tengo ahora, si lo consigo publicaré la respuesta, muchas gracias a todos c:

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar tu clase `Baraja`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías implementar el siguiente código. Asumiendo que tu clase Baraja tiene 2 propiedades llamadas *número* y *palo*, (`int` y `String` respectivamente). Independientemente de cómo implementes tu clase, la idea es escoger la cantidad de barajas aleatoriamente de acuerdo a lo que indique el usuario.

Para ello, debemos generar un número aleatorio entre 1 y 12, ya que la baraja española contiene 4 palos con números entre 1 y 12. También debemos escoger aleatoriamente el palo (*Bastos*, *Espadas*, *Copas*, *Oros*).

Para lograrlo voy a tomar una clase baraja muy simple, y los valores (*String*) de los palos los almacenaré fuera de la clase en un `Array`. Lo que haré será generar números aleatorios entre 0 y 3, que indicarán el valor del índice del `Array`, así seleccionaré un palo al azar.

El código quedaría así:

```
import java.util.*;

class Baraja {
  private String palo;
  private int numero;

  public static void Baraja() {

  }

  public Baraja(int _numero, String _palo) {
    this.numero = _numero;
    this.palo = _palo;
  }

  public String getPalo() {
    return this.palo;
  }

  public int getNumero() {
    return this.numero;
  }

  public void setPalo(String _palo) {
    this.palo = _palo;
  }

  public void setNumero(int _numero) {
    this.numero = _numero;
  }
}

public class baraja_aleatoria{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Palo[] = {"Oros","Bastos","Espadas","Copas"}; //Array con el valor de los palos de la baraja
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Diga el número de cartas que desea:");
    int cantidad = sc.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Baraja> barajas = new ArrayList<Baraja>();
    while (cantidad > 0) {
      int numero = ((int) Math.round(Math.random() * 11)) + 1; // produce números entre 1 y 12 aleatoriamente
      int p = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 3); // produce números entre 0 y 3 aleatoriamente
      boolean existe = false;
      Baraja baraja = new Baraja(numero, Palo[p]); // Creamos la baraja
      for(int i = 0; i < barajas.size(); i++) {
        if(numero == barajas.get(i).getNumero() && Palo[p] == barajas.get(i).getPalo()) { // comparamos la baraja con las ya almacenadas
          existe = true;
          break; // Si la baraja ya fue seleccionada no se sigue verificando
        }
      }
      if(!existe) {
        barajas.add(baraja); // solo añadimos la baraja si es diferente a todas las ya escogidas
        cantidad--;
      }
    }
  barajas.forEach(baraja -> System.out.println("Baraja: " + baraja.getNumero() + " de " + baraja.getPalo()));
  }
}
```

Esto produce la siguiente salida:

[image: Ejemplo de salida de código]

Como puedes apreciar en el código, he cambiado tus 2 bucle `for` anidados por un bucle `for` anidado dentro de un bucle `while`. La idea que tienes de alterar el índice de tu bucle externo es mejor realizarla usando un bucle `while`.

En cada iteración (`cantidad > 0`) del bucle `while` se genera una nueva baraja. Luego se realiza una comparación de dicha baraja con las que ya están almacenadas en nuestro `ArrayList`. Si la baraja no existe en nuestro `ArrayList` entonces se puede añadir y se reduce el valor de `cantidad`, de lo contrario se vuelve a jecutar otra corrida para obtener una nueva baraja.

De esta forma puedes obtener la cantidad de barajas aleatoriamente que requieras sin repetición.

Si ejecutas el programa pidiendo 49 barajas, el mismo se quedará en un bucle infinito, debido a que la última baraja que genere siempre estará repetida y el valor `cantidad` siempre será mayor que cero.

Espero que esta respuesta aclare tu duda.

Comment: Eres un dios muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Se puede optimizar mucho más pero te lo dejo muy básico. Un método llamado `generaCarta()`, que tiene un bucle que da vueltas hasta que se hayan generado los aleatorios necesarios que no se encuentren en el mazo.

Uso `int` para palo y numero, después en el `toString();` transformo a Oros, Copas, Espadas, Bastos.

> Carta.java

```
public class Carta {

    private int numero;
    private int palo;

    public Carta(int numero, int palo) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.palo = palo;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public int getPalo() {
        return palo;
    }

    public void setPalo(int palo) {
        this.palo = palo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String paloString = "";

        switch (this.palo) {
            case 1:
                paloString = "Oros";
                break;
            case 2:
                paloString = "Bastos";
                break;
            case 3:
                paloString = "Espadas";
                break;
            case 4:
                paloString = "Copas";
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("error");
        }

        return "Carta: " + numero + " de " + paloString;
    }

}
```

> Principal.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Principal {

    public static ArrayList<Carta> mazo = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Generamos 10
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mazo.add(generaCarta());
        }

        //Mostramos las 10.
        for (int i = 0; i < mazo.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(mazo.get(i).toString());
        }

    }

    //Generamos Carta sin Repetir.
    public static Carta generaCarta() {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        Carta n;
        boolean found;
        int numero, palo;

        do {

            found = false;
            numero = rnd.nextInt(12 - 1 + 1) + 1;
            palo = rnd.nextInt(4 - 1 + 1) + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < mazo.size(); i++) {
                if (mazo.get(i).getNumero() == numero && mazo.get(i).getPalo() == palo) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        } while (found);

        return new Carta(numero, palo);
    }

}
```